# How can i validate a csv files with datatypes, email type, boolean type?

Tags: spring, csv, validation

I want to validate a csv file. It has been converted from an excel file which contains numeric, date, boolean, text fields. So i need to validate the csv file. I've used one Csvvalidator but it doesn't works right.

```
List<Field> list = new ArrayList<Field>();

        list.add(new Field(1, Type.TEXT, notOptional));                 //emailaddress  
        list.add(new Field(2, Type.TEXT, notOptional));                 //firstname
        list.add(new Field(3, Type.TEXT, notOptional));                 //middlename
        list.add(new Field(4, Type.TEXT, optional));                    //lastname
        list.add(new Field(5, Type.DATE, optional));                    //dob
        list.add(new Field(6, Type.TEXT, notOptional));                 //gender
        list.add(new Field(7, Type.TEXT, optional));                    //altemailaddress
        list.add(new Field(8, Type.TEXT, optional));                    //currentStreet1
        list.add(new Field(9, Type.TEXT, optional));                    //currentStreet2
        list.add(new Field(10, Type.TEXT, optional));                   //currentCity
        list.add(new Field(11, Type.TEXT, optional));                   //currentState
        list.add(new Field(12, Type.NUMBER, optional));                 //currentPincode
        list.add(new Field(13, Type.TEXT, optional));                   //permanentStreet1
        list.add(new Field(14, Type.TEXT, optional));                   //permanentStreet2
        list.add(new Field(15, Type.TEXT, optional));                   //permanentCity
        list.add(new Field(16, Type.TEXT, optional));                   //permanentState
        list.add(new Field(17, Type.NUMBER, optional));                 //permanentPincode
        list.add(new Field(18, Type.NUMBER, optional));                 //mobile
        list.add(new Field(19, Type.NUMBER, notOptional));              //phone
        list.add(new Field(20, Type.TEXT, optional));                   //emailsubscription
        list.add(new Field(21, Type.TEXT, optional));                   //mobilesubscription
        System.out.println(list.size());

        CsvValidator validator = new CsvValidatorImpl(AppConstants.OUTPUT_FILE, list, "|");
```

The excel and csv has 21 fields but when i compile it, it says these things.

line 1 is invalid, contains 165 required 21 fields.

line 2 is invalid, contains 157 required 21 fields

line 3 is invalid, contains 161 required 21 fields.

line 4 is invalid, contains 137 required 21 fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [SuperCSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_reading.html) - it allows you to read file easily and define type for each column in a row.